# Creating table with JS from input

Tags: javascript, html-table

I need to create a table from input with JS. So it works not completely, maybe you know what's wrong. I need to add border-style, border-color, border-width. But the elements don't work together. And how to remove counter from cells?

```js
getS('.btn-create-table').onclick = function() {
  console.log(event.target)

  const countTr = table.countTr.value;
  const countTd = table.countTd.value;
  const widthTd = table.widthTd.value;
  const heightTd = table.heightTd.value;
  const borderWidth = table.borderWidth.value;
  const borderType = table.borderType.value;
  const borderColor = table.borderColor.value;

  for (let i = 0; i < countTr; i++) {
    getS('.edit-area').value += `<table>  <tr style=""> ${i}  </tr>`
    for (let h = 0; h < countTd; h++) {
      getS('.edit-area').value += `<td style= "width: ${widthTd}, height: ${heightTd}, border-style: ${borderType}, border-width: ${borderWidth}, border-color: ${borderColor}"> ${h}  TD </td> `;

      console.log(borderType, borderColor, borderWidth)
    }
  }

  getS('.edit-area').value += '</table>';
  getS('.first').classList.add('show') //show block
  getS('.second').classList.remove('show') // hide block
}
```

Comment: What is `getS()`? Is it a short name for `document.querySelector()`?

Comment: Why are you putting the table into the value of an input instead of `innerHTML` of a div?

Comment: From where is the `table` var from? Is it an object populated by a library before? We are lacking some important details in order to help you. Please provide the full code, so that we can run it in the snippet.

Comment: Can you edit this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing and what debugging you have done?

Comment: You can't put `${i}` directly into a `<tr>`. You need to put it in a `<td>` or `<th>`.

Comment: Instead of inline styles, use CSS classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your mistake is using `,` commas:

```
getS('.edit-area').value += `<td style= "width: ${widthTd}, height: ${heightTd}, border-style: ${borderType}, border-width: ${borderWidth}, border-color: ${borderColor}"> ${h}  TD </td> `;
//                                                        ^                    ^
```

Style should be split with `;` semicolons

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean to do this.

To use table.someName.value, you need to have a form

This code creates valid HTML. I would suggest you create a stylesheet instead of giving each cell an inline style

Your invalid HTML had

- counter inside a tr tag
- commas between the style statements instead of semicolon
- missing tbody and end rows

```js
const tableForm = document.getElementById('tableForm');
tableForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const countTr = tableForm.countTr.value;
  const countTd = tableForm.countTd.value;
  const widthTd = tableForm.widthTd.value;
  const heightTd = tableForm.heightTd.value;
  const borderWidth = tableForm.borderWidth.value;
  const borderStyle = tableForm.borderStyle.value;
  const borderColor = tableForm.borderColor.value;
  const html = ['<table><tbody>'];
  for (let i = 0; i < countTr; i++) {
    html.push('<tr style="">');
    for (let j = 0; j < countTd; j++) {
      html.push(`<td style= "width: ${widthTd}; height: ${heightTd}; border-style: ${borderStyle}; border-width: ${borderWidth}; border-color: ${borderColor}">Row ${i} cell ${j}</td> `);
    }
    html.push('</tr>');
  }
  html.push('</tbody></table>');
  console.log( html.join(''))
  document.querySelector('.edit-area').value = html.join('');
});
```

```html
<form id="tableForm">
  <label>TR<input type="number" name="countTr" value="0" /></label><label>TD<input type="number" name="countTd" value="0" /></label><br/>
  <label>Width<input type="number" name="widthTd" value="0" /></label><label>Height<input type="number" name="heightTd" value="0" /></label><br/>
  <label>Border width<input type="number" name="borderWidth" value="0" /></label>
  <label>Border type<select name="borderStyle">
    <option>none</option>
    <option>hidden</option>
    <option>dotted</option>
    <option>dashed</option>
    <option>solid</option>
    <option>double</option>
    <option>groove</option>
    <option>ridge</option>
    <option>inset</option>
    <option>outset</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>Border color<input type="text" name="borderColor" value="" /></label>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" />
<textarea class="edit-area"></textarea>
</form>
```